# How do I resolve ADB shell error device not found?

Tags: adb, amazon-fire-tv

Currently trying to connect my firestick to ADB shell to stop it from automatically going to sleep but when I open the shell I get the message:

```
C:\adblink>echo off
adb.exe: device 'IP Address' not found.
```

I set the firestick to developer mode, told it to allow ADB debugging, and then tried to connect my laptop to it via the IP. I got a pop up on my firestick when I tried to connect to it and I told it to always allow my computer access to the device. The ADB GUI says I'm connected by IP, but when I open the shell I get that error.

Update: tried plugging the firestick into my laptop via USB and that allowed me to access it through the shell. If you encounter this issue yourself try that.